# Flutter: Como puedo hacer un salto de línea dentro de un texto string con .split?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, split

Estoy aprendiendo flutter, y me encantaría dar saltos de linea al contenido dentro de un string.

Por ejemplo

```
String description = "*Este contenido es en inglés* | This book is about the science ant ict technologies. | The ict is information and com.."
```

Me gustaría tomar la varibale `description` y con un `.split` poder encontrar cada `|` y hacerle un salto de linea para poder mostrarlo en pantalla.

Algo como esto seria el resultado final:

> Este contenido es en inglés.
>
> This book is about the science ant ict technologies.
>
> The ict is information and com..

De que forma podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar el método `replaceAll` de `String`, algo así:

```dart
 String description = "*Este contenido es en inglés* | This book is about the science ant ict technologies. | The ict is information and com..";

 String newDescription = description.replaceAll("|", "\n");
  
 print(newDescription);
```

Resultado:

```
*Este contenido es en inglés* 
 This book is about the science ant ict technologies. 
 The ict is information and com..
```

Si deseas también puedes separarlo por ese caracter y obtener un listado de Strings que corresponde a cada linea, algo así:

```dart
 List<String> splits = description.split('|');
  
for(String item in splits){
  print(item);
}
```

Resultado:

```
*Este contenido es en inglés* 
 This book is about the science ant ict technologies. 
 The ict is information and com..
```

Aquí te dejo más info sobre `String` y sus propiedades: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String-class.html